# program that keeps accepting three numbers, and prints the maximum among the three

Tags: c, if-statement, dynamic, conditional-statements

the program that keeps accepting three numbers, and prints the maximum among the three.
I am getting runtime error(SIGABRT)
here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char ch[30];
    char *c[3];
    long int i[3], mx_2;
    int o;
    while((fgets(ch,sizeof(ch),stdin))&&ch!='\0')
    {
        c[0] = (char *)malloc(10);
        c[1] = (char *)malloc(10);
        c[2] = (char *)malloc(10);
        c[0] = strtok(ch," ");
        c[1] = strtok(NULL," ");
        c[2] = strtok(NULL," ");
        i[0] = atoi(c[0]);
        i[1] = atoi(c[1]);
        i[2] = atoi(c[2]);
        mx_2 = i[0] > i[1] ? (i[0] >i[2] ? i[0] : i[2]) : (i[1] > i[2] ? i[1] : i[2]);
        printf("%ld\n",mx_2);
        fflush(stdin);
        for (o = 0; o < 3; o++) {
            free(c[o]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

any help guys
thanks

Comment: Perform `i[0]=atoi(c[0]);` immediately after `c[0]=strtok(ch," ");` and check for `c[0] != NULL`.  Similar for `i[1]=atoi(c[1]); i[2]=atoi(c[2]);`

Comment: Note that `ch!='\0'` is always false, since you're comparing the address of `ch` to `'\0'`.

Comment: `free(c[o]);` this point cannot free it because return value of `malloc` rewrite by return value of `strtok` (malloc and free is not required.)

Comment: As ever: please don't cast the return value of `malloc` & co in C (you have to in C++, but in C it's considered bad practice)

Comment: http://ideone.com/geaGWC

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks bro,but why we don't need malloc here and thanks everyone

Comment: see link  in my previous comment.

Comment: Because you are not using the allocated area.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  appreciated but just one more thing,what about in a loop like this

Comment: @BLUEPIXY http://ideone.com/N4RQH3

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY why it is showing error in loop

Comment: You need to set the input of the standard input. E.g 1<newline>1 2 3<newline>

Comment: a bit more detail please

Comment: Enter the string to be used as input in the column of `enter input (stdin)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `c[0] = malloc(10);` and some sentences later you do `c[0] = strtok(...);` you are overwriting **the pointer value** at `c[0]` with the result of `strtok(3)` (which is itself a pointer), not copying the string contents.  When you reach the `for` loop of `free(3)` you are passing to the `free()` function the values given by `strtok` and not the ones given from `malloc()` (these were lost forever, when you reassigned the array `c` values) so that's the most probable cause of your `SIGABRT`.

By the way, you don't even need to do any of the `malloc`'s and `free`'s you do in your program.  Just get a buffer long enough to store a whole line of input, and then use strtok to get all the chunks.  On other side, you have to test the `strtok` result, as if there's no more data (you input only two values) it will return `NULL`.

This piece of code will do the work and not only for three values, but for any number up to the array size:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for input output routines like fgets */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for the constant EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MAX and INT_MIN */
#include <string.h> /* for strtok */

int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
        /* we have one full line of input up to sizeof buffer chars.  */
        int max = INT_MIN;
        int min = INT_MAX;
        char *s = strtok(buffer, " \t\n");
        if (!s) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid line\n");
            continue;
        }
        while (s) {
            int x = atoi(s);
            if (x > max) max = x;
            if (x < min) min = x;
            s = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        }
        if (max != INT_MIN)
            printf("MAX: %d\n", max);
        if (min != INT_MAX)
            printf("MIN: %d\n", min);
    } /* while */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /* main */
```

Comment: thanks but what about if we use it in a loop like this, why runtime error http://ideone.com/N4RQH3

Comment: Well, in the code in your link you don't check the possible `NULL` value returned from `strtok`, and, if you just hit enter (without a number) all values will be `NULL` (even the first one) and you'll be trying `atoi(NULL);` which shouts the `SEGFAULT` runtime.  In my loop I stop as soon as `strtok` returns `NULL`, so I don't fall in your case.  Look that if you hit return in my case, you don't get anything but a message saying `"Invalid line"`, as you have no data to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Better use scanf for your task:

```
 scanf(" %d %d %d", i, i+1, i+2);//note the leading space in the format
```

Comment: added a leading space to the `scanf` format to skip over whitespace in the buffer

Comment: use `%ld` instead of `%d`. _leading space in the format_ is not required.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Not required, but recommended , especially considering the OP is going to be calling `scanf` in a loop\

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem There is no need to be about to be called in a loop. `%d` to skip the prior whitespaces .

Comment: the `%ld` format is required if you are dealing with `long` s.  In 32bit architectures, they are the same, but not in 16bit architectures and you'll get U.B.